# Tab characters converted to spaces in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script I am writing that combines a number of reports into a consolidated tab-delimited (TSV) format. However, I am noticing that whenever I write to file, the tabs in my strings are being converted into spaces. Is there some other string literal that I should use?

```
    var content = 
        data.parameters.time[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.url[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.code_name[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.app_name[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.version[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.cookies[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.lang[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.platform[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.user_agent[0] + "\t" +
        data.parameters.ex[0];
    fld.createFile(makeid() + ".tab", content, ContentService.MimeType.CSV);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with using the `\t` string literal - rather you're using the wrong `MimeType` enum, from the [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/mime-type). DriveApp methods expect `MimeType` [as a string](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type). Try:

```js
fld.createFile(makeid() + ".tab", content, MimeType.CSV);
```

Here's a snippet that shows the tab characters survive the file write when the MimeType is properly set:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var content = 
        'time' + "\t" +
        'url' + "\t" +
        'code_name' + "\t" +
        'etcetera';
  Logger.log("Initial TSV: " + JSON.stringify(content.split("\t")));

  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile("Delete-me" + ".tab", content, MimeType.CSV);

  // Check our result, by reading back the file
  var blob = newFile.getBlob();
  var docContent = blob.getDataAsString()
  Logger.log("Result TSV: " + JSON.stringify(docContent.split("\t")));
}
```

Logs:

```js
[15-04-07 14:53:08:767 EDT] Initial TSV: ["time","url","code_name","etcetera"]
[15-04-07 14:53:09:542 EDT] Result TSV: ["time","url","code_name","etcetera"]
```