# Google Apps Script: Tab character turns into space

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a string literal and want to display it. However the tabs get converted to spaces.

```
var s = "Row" + "\t" + "Email \n";  
ui.alert("String: ", s, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
```

How can I fix this? The answer here doesn't apply to me [Tab characters converted to spaces in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498324/tab-characters-converted-to-spaces-in-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface ui.alert removes whitespace (more than one space). If you show it in Logger.log you will see a tab distance.

Though there is an alternative to show a window in your spreadsheet: ui.showModalDialog. 
It makes use of html and in html you can force spaces to be print by &nbsp. You will have to replace your \t with four times &nbsp and show it in the modalDialog. Good luck !

```
function TabsInModalDialog() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var title = "Tabs allowed";
  var message = "Hi there!\tLet's make use of the Tab!\t\tThese were two tabs\t\t\tAnd these were three even!";
  var html = message.replace(/\t/g,"&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"); // this replaces the tab \t with four spaces, &nbsp is special code for a space in html.
  html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  ui.showModalDialog(html, title);
}
```

Comment: No, indeed. the alert window removes whitespace more than one space.